# One to Many KStream-KTable join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kStream of Universities -
when University is -

```
University(universityId: String, name: String, studentIds: Seq[String])

val universityKStream = builder.stream[String, University](...)
```

And a kTable of Students,
when Student is -

```
Student(studentId: String, name: String)

val studentsKtable = builder.table[String, Student](...)
```

I want to join the two and produce to a topic of ResolvedUniverity objects:

```
ResolvedUniversity(universityId: String, name: String, students: Seq[Student])
```

I cant groupBy and aggregate students with universityId, since universityId field doesn't exist in Student object..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using just the DSL, I think the simplest you can do is (Java):

```java
    class Student {
        String studentId;
        String name;
    }
    class University {
        String universityId;
        String name;
        List<String> studentIds;
    }
    class ResolvedUniversity {
        String universityId;
        String name;
        List<Student> students;
    }
    Serde<String> stringSerde = null;
    Serde<Student> studentSerde = null;
    Serde<University> universitySerde = null;
    Serde<ResolvedUniversity> resolvedUniversitySerde = null;

    KStream<String, University> universities = topology
      .stream("universities", Consumed.with(stringSerde, universitySerde));

    KTable<String, Student> students = topology
      .table("students", Consumed.with(stringSerde, studentSerde));

    KTable<String, ResolvedUniversity> resolvedUniversities = universities
      .flatMap((k, v) -> {
          return v.studentIds.stream()
            .map(id -> new KeyValue<>(id, v))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
      })
      .join(students, Pair::pair, Joined.with(stringSerde, universitySerde, studentSerde))
      .groupBy((k, v) -> v.left().universityId)
      .aggregate(ResolvedUniversity::new,
                 (k, v, a) -> {
                     a.universityId = v.left().universityId;
                     a.name = v.left().name;
                     a.students.add(v.right());
                     return a;
                 },
                 Materialized.with(stringSerde, resolvedUniversitySerde));
```

With this type of join, for historical processing your `KTable` of universities must be "primed" with its data before the `KStream` is joined against it.